# How to flash a custom rom on galaxy on5 pro

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, custom-roms, 7.1-nougat, 8.1-oreo

I'm an Android fan and I have a Samsung Galaxy On5 Pro.
It is currently running Android Marshmallow `6.1`.
I want it to get upgraded to Android Nougat `7.1.1`.
I don't have a recovery.
How can I install TWRP?
How do I do it?
Edit:
I got TWRP and installed android nougat `7.1.1`
How do I install android `8.1`?

Answer (score 1):

Root your device at your own risk!

1. Check your device model number. (for SM-G550FY/SM-G550T1/SM-G5500T2/SM-G5500 only)
2. Select TWRP Based on the mobile model number.
3. Make sure your device battery is charged above 50%
4. Backup your current files and data, just in case (save them on external storage).
5. Flash TWRP using odin
6. Install SuperSU.

For detailed information see https://www.androidinfotech.com/root-samsung-galaxy-on5-sm-g550-lollipop-marshmallow/ and https://rootmydevice.com/root-samsung-galaxy-on5-pro/